# How to crawl component-based web applications built by Vue and React?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js, web-crawler, abot

I want to crawl my SPA built by the Vue framework (Relatively same as React framework). However, I see that the content is not rendered while crawling. The result is:

```
 <!doctype html>
 <HTML>
  <body>
   <div id=app>
    </div>
     <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/manifest.2ae2e69a05c33dfc65f8.js></script> 
     <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/vendor.60c471696de493d48a1c.js></script>
     <script type=text/javascript src=/static/js/app.335a9e9866cb7dc6a517.js></script>
  </body>
 </html>
```

Are the component-based javascript frameworks anti crawling? How can I make the component to be rendered by the crawler?

I'm using `Abot` framework for crawling propose

Comment: FWIW, this is the problem that universal frameworks like Next and Nuxt solve if you care about how the site is represented to other crawlers, most importantly search engine bots.

Comment: @EstusFlask, One of my goals is SEO analysis. I see there are a lot of works Improving SEO of SPA using js frameworks.

Comment: Then that's it, in order to improve the situation you need to either use universal framework. or crawl client-only SPA with your crawler that uses headless browser (like the answer suggests) and serve rendered html files to consumers (known as prerender service)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Abot does is send a request to the target website, parse the data, and pass it back to you. As you probably know, frameworks like React or Vue are 100% JavaScript based, meaning no data will be rendered unless you run the JavaScript. So the solution here is to launch a headless browser or another DOM engine and scrape the data.

Several engines you could use are Selenium (browser automation framework available in Python and some other languages), Puppeteer (Chromium-based web-scraper in NodeJS), or a DOM engine like JSDOM.

Moral of the story is: if you want to see result rendered by JavaScript you must execute the JavaScript inside a DOM.